# Hardware recommendation for zookeeper in hadoop cluster

Tags: hadoop, apache-zookeeper

I have a light-weight Hadoop environment:

2 namenodes(job tracker/HBase Master) + 3 datanodes(tasktracker/HBase Region)

They are all like two quad-core CPUs + 16-24G memory + total 15T

I am wondering what server specs the zookeepers would look like if I were to go for 3 zookeepers? Can anyone share some experience?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [HBase's perpective](http://hbase.apache.org/book/zookeeper.html#how_many_zks) -

> Give each ZooKeeper server around 1GB of RAM, and if possible, its own
>   dedicated disk (A dedicated disk is the best thing you can do to
>   ensure a performant ZooKeeper ensemble). For very heavily loaded
>   clusters, run ZooKeeper servers on separate machines from
>   RegionServers (DataNodes and TaskTrackers).

-Dedicated disk should be configured to store snapshots as the transaction logs grows.

-Suffcient RAM is requried so that it doesn't swap.